# Exact meaning of this xpath

Tags: xpath, xpath-3.0, xpath-3.1

I came across this XPath string...

`courses[?(@.id==101)].students[?(@.id==111)]`

I'm not even sure if it is valid XPath because of how '?' and '.' are used. And it doesn't work in many online XPath evaluators.

Although, in XPath 3, there is a lookup operator ('?') and some JSON scanning features. Refer: https://www.altova.com/training/xpath3/xpath-31#lookup-operator

So, I'm wondering what exactly the purpose of the '?()' and '.' are.

So far I'm guessing that this expression is being used to search into a JSON content within an XML.

Guessing the JSON object is like this:

```
{
    "courses":[
        {
            'id':'101', 
            'name':'Course 101', 
            'students':[
                { 
                    'id':'111', 
                    'name':'Student 111' 
                }
            ]
        }   
    ]
}
```

In short, is it a valid XPath 3 expression? And if yes, then what exactly are '?()' and '.' doing?

Comment: Oops... came to know it is a JsonPath expression. It just had misleading variable and class names.

Comment: You should reformulate the question to be about json in order to have meaning.

Answer (score 0):

JSON can only work with double quotes